# UseSpaStaticFiles() not found after migrating to dotnet Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

After upgrading my `.NetCore 2.2` application to `Net Core 3.1`. I am now facing issue in the `startup.cs` file related to a `UseSpaStaticFiles()` method.

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app
            .UseCors("default")
            .UseStaticFiles()
            .UseSpaStaticFiles(); // this line is giving me error.
       .....
    }
```

The error says :

> Error CS1061  'IApplicationBuilder' does not contain a definition for
>   'UseSpaStaticFiles' and no accessible extension method
>   'UseSpaStaticFiles' accepting a first argument of type
>   'IApplicationBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

To resolve the issue I have tried installing `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices` package from [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices/3.1.0?_src=template) and that also didn't help.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This method is contained in the

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions
```

NuGet package.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions

Answer (score 6):

The [ASP.NET Core 2.2 to 3.0 migration guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30) explains that some assemblies were removed from the main ASP.NET Core package to reduce the deployment size and allow people to only include what they really need.

The section [Add package references for removed assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#add-package-references-for-removed-assemblies). That section includes a list of the removed assemblies and the packages that need to be added back.

For SPA Services, the packages are [Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices) and [Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions)

3.0 is a major version so breaking changes are expected. The [Breaking Changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#breaking-api-changes) links to list of breaking changes by category and the detailed Github work issues